# Saving core data entity in popover in SwiftUI throws nilError without passing .environment to SubView again

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

Playin' with SwiftUI and Core Data brought me into a curious problem. So the situation is the following:

I have a main view "AppView" and a sub view named "SubView". The SubView view will be opened from the AppView view if I click the plus button in the NavigationTitleBar as popover or sheet.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@State private var modal: Bool = false
...
Button(action: {
        self.modal.toggle()
      }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
      }.popover(isPresented: self.$modal){
        SubView()
      }
```

The SubView view has a little form with two TextField objects to add a forename and a surname. The inputs of this two objects are handled by two separate @State properties. The third object in this form is simple button, which should save a the fore- and surname to an attached Customer Entity for CoreData.

```
...
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
...
Button(action: {
  let customerItem = Customer(context: self.managedObjectContext)
  customerItem.foreName = self.forename
  customerItem.surname = self.surname

  do {
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
}) {
  Text("Speichern")
}
```

If I try to save the Customer entity this way, I get the error: "nilError", specially: "Unresolved error Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)", [:]" from NSError.

But after figuring out, that when I add `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)` to the SubView() call like so `SubView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)` it's works like a charm.

Does anyone know, why I need to pass the managedObjectContext a second time? I thought, that I just need to pass the managedObjectContext one time to use it in the whole view hierarchy, like in the SceneDelegate.swift:

```
    // Get the managed object context from the shared persistent container.
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
    // Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
    let contentView = AppView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

Is it because calling the SubView() this way, the view is not part of the view hierarchy? I don't understand it...

Comment: I observed same behavior on iOS 13.1. Xcode 11.1

Comment: You aren't the first to find this problem, I solved it by passing the context as a parameter. Hopefully Apple will fix it soon.

Comment: As expected this seems to be a bug in the Compiler of Swift/SwiftUI. So Harlan Haskins from Apple gave me the confirmation for that: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11607 - So I hope this will be fixed soon. For the quick fix: Passing .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context) to the SubView popover works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

WOW THIS DROVE ME NUTS! Especially because the errors tells you absolutely no information as to how to fix.

Here is the fix until the bug in Xcode is resolved:

```
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.add = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Add Todo List")
            }).sheet(isPresented: $add, content: {
                AddTodoListView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
            })
        )
```

Just add `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)` to your secondary view (a Modal, in this example).

Comment: immense help for all of us brave enough to develop in SwiftUI right now...

Comment: Solved my problem as well. Thank you.

Comment: My dude! Why does SwiftUI make this necessary? Environment should be accessed globally.

Comment: But why is it necessary? Really strange that SwiftUI does not make it automatically...

Comment: It's necessary because it is the only solution to the bug right now. Apple is apparently working on a fix. Remember SwiftUI is still very new.

Comment: Can I use it in popover too?

Comment: Yes, you can @davidev.

Comment: ` Especially because the errors tells you absolutely no information as to how to fix.` no error message provided by Xcode gives any clue about the real error. Xcode and the documentation provided by Apple are mediocre.

Comment: This was very helpful. I had a similar error. The mistake I made is that I was calling a CoreData update function from init(). When I moved it to onAppear instead, everything worked correctly.