# Receiving NSError "Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0."

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to simply save a core data record.

Code:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@State var title: String = ""
@State var selectedColor: UIColor? = ColorConstants.defaultColor

// more irrelevant code here

Button(action: {
    let todoList = TodoList(context: self.managedObjectContext)
    todoList.title = self.title
    todoList.color = self.selectedColor

    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print(error.localizedFailureReason)
        print(self.title)
        print(self.selectedColor)
    }
}, label: {
    Text("Save")
})
```

This is printing:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)
nil
Test
Optional(<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600001daf300; name = systemRedColor>)
```

I have the `title` set to a `String`, and the `color` set to a `Transformable` in Core Data.

I have no idea how to fix this. I've found nothing about this error online.

Comment: FINALLY found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328201/saving-core-data-entity-in-popover-in-swiftui-throws-nilerror-without-passing-e

Comment: What was printing `print(error)`? It might have more infos.

Comment: Just ‘nilError’ but the solution was that the managed object context wasn’t making it to the next view despite being declared in scenedelegate