# Encountering "nilError" when saving new Core Data entity in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm building an app using SwiftUI and Core Data, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to save a new Core Data entity. I'm getting a "nilError" when attempting to save the entity, and I'm having trouble pinpointing the root cause of this issue.

Here's the relevant code snippet

```
// Inside EmptyProjectView.swift

Button(action: {
    let projectName = "New Project \(String(format: "%02d", worktime.count + 1))"
    let newWorkTime = WorkTime(context: viewContext)
    newWorkTime.name = projectName
    newWorkTime.elapsedSeconds = 0
    newWorkTime.isRunning = false
    newWorkTime.timestamp = Date()

    do {
        // The error occurs on the line below
        try viewContext.save()
        selectedProjectIndex = worktime.count - 1
    } catch {
        print(projectName)
        print(newWorkTime)
        print("Error saving new WorkTime: \(error)")
    }
}) {
    // Button content
}
```

I'm consistently getting the "nilError" during **`viewContext.save()`**. I've checked that **`projectName`** is generating a non-nil value and that **`newWorkTime.name`** is being assigned a value, so it's unclear why I'm encountering this error.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

- I'm using Xcode 15.0.1
- I've confirmed that the Core Data model has a "name" attribute for the "WorkTime" entity.

Here are the steps I've taken and the things I've checked so far:

I've confirmed that projectName is generating a non-nil value.
I've checked that newWorkTime.name is being assigned a value before calling save().
I've ensured that the Core Data model has a "name" attribute for the "WorkTime" entity.
Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the "nilError" during viewContext.save().

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue or suggest additional troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328201/saving-core-data-entity-in-popover-in-swiftui-throws-nilerror-without-passing-e

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does fetching and saving work fine in other parts of the app?